# Vertical lines in the site header

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design

I noticed that the site header was suddenly showing a series of vertical bars. These appeared to be where the header image repeated.

[image]

I opened the site in chrome dev tools and was able to remove the bars by disabling the svg background image.

The relevant CSSS is:

```
background-image: url("img/header-bg.png?v=4270316d9fec");
background-image: url("img/header-bg.svg?v=6d7dc0e93333"),none;
```

After chatting with @undo and @jon_ericson it appears the issue is only present at some zoom levels.

Jon said he would ask a designer to look into the issue.

Chrome 52 on Win10

Comment: As per chat I get this at 90%, 75%, and <= 30% (not 100+, or 50 and 67).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for reporting this. Fix is already waiting in repo for build,so it should be live in next couple hours.

Comment: Thanks very much - that was very quick work on what can only be called an edge case.